# Using AMPScript to dynamically display email messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Apologies if I'm not explaining this very well but I am pretty new to AMPScript.

So what I'm trying to achieve is basically dynamic content. If a person's course in the data extension matches what I am querying in my code then I would like the content to be displayed.

I've managed to do something similar with "ContentBlockByKey" but I need it to display an Email message (not a content block) hence why I am using AMPscript for this and not the dynamic content features in MC. Is this possible? I see something called AssetID and EmailID on the Email Message but just not sure how to pull it in.

**Here's a code snippet:**

```ampscript
<!--
%%[
SET @attr = Lookup('Base Data Extension','Course','Person Contact ID',_SubscriberKey)

IF @attr == 'Art' THEN
SET @thumbnail = ContentBlockByKey("c4ef80b7-00c2-4391-8b8b-7f62ef6dc91f")
ELSE
SET @thumbnail = ContentBlockByKey("383b21e9-656f-4adb-a238-5ffb37fce323")
ENDIF
]%%
--><table>

  <tr>
   <td>
    %%=v(@thumbnail)=%%</td></tr></table>`
```

Comment: So, what you want to do, is to show a complete email within another email?

Comment: Thats right, see my comment below about using decision splits and why I’m looking at ampscript as a option

Comment: This is not a viable solution. You would normally have build your emails dynamically, replacing few content blocks depending on the nature of the email you wish to send. There is no way of using ampscript to get the complete HTML of an email in content builder, and having this content placed in another email.

Comment: Fair enough. The only reason I didn't build them dynamically is that the whole email is different. How would you address a track that had 40 variants for 1 email and 20 for the next?

Comment: The whole point of Content Builder is the ability of replace selected parts of the email, making it as reusable as possible. Allowing you to have a single template, and include/exclude content blocks where needed. Your case sounds like the emails you are using have all probably been built using HTML paste method, taking away the benefits of content builder.

Comment: This is not recommended, which is why not putting as an answer - but if you build out each of the 40 versions as code snippet blocks and then have the entirety of your email be conditional if statements calling in the contentblock depending on the condition, you could meet your need. But this is a really shite way to do it with a ton of risks, bloated processing and difficult maintenance (among other things). I think you need to go back to look at the overall solution again and rethink execution and strategy on it - this seems like forcing something to fit rather than getting it right

Answer (score -2):

This could easily be accomplished with Journey Builder, rather than AMPScript.

1. Users would enter the Journey when they are added to the specific **Data Extension**
2. A **Decision Split** would determine the **Course**
3. The appropriate **Email** would be sent based on the **Decision Split**

In regards to Dynamic Content and AMPScript, it is best to have 1 Email Content, and several Content Blocks that can be used dynamically using AMPScript.

[image]

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned, there would be around 40 decision splits for the first email and then 20 something for a email later in the journey and your limited to 20 decisions on Journey builder right? I could have multiple decision splits true but I think that could get quiet messy hence why I wanted to do something with ampscript.